# Whenever I try to put values to the training data it shows key error

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
fruits  = pd.read_csv('fruit_data_with_colors.txt')
fruits.head()
X= fruits['mass','height','width']

> Error - KeyError                                  Traceback (most
> recent call last)
> C:\Python\Python37\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2656             try:
> -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError: ('mass', 'height', 'width')
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-13-f018d289c28d> in <module>
> ----> 1 X= fruits['mass','height','width']
> 
> C:\Python\Python37\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> __getitem__(self, key)    2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2928             if is_integer(indexer):    2929                 indexer = [indexer]
> 
> C:\Python\Python37\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2657                
> return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
> -> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2660        
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
> 2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError: ('mass', 'height', 'width')
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What do you understand from that error? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately - this is a `pandas` one, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (edited). For the future, it will be better to also format your error trace as code, and omit any irrelevant parts from the code, including irrelevant imports (done it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last line to

```
X = fruits[['mass','height','width']]
```